# e.preventDefault and timer could not stop sweet alert pop up box from disappearing in less than 1s

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I have used Django to develop a web app.

I used Sweet Alert JavaScript plugin for pop up box.
However, the 2nd pop up box disappears in less than 1 s without clicking ok button to confirm.

Even after using e.preventDefault, the second pop up box of Sweet Alert still disappears in less than 1s.

How to prevent the quick disappear of the 2nd Sweet alert pop up box?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/demo/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

  function myFunction(e)
  {
    
    Swal.fire
    ({
        title: '',
        text: "Do you want to confirm entries?",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
        cancelButtonText: 'No'
    }).then
       (
         (result) =>
         {
            if (result.value)
            {
                $("#myform").submit();
                //sleep(500);
                $.ajax
                ({
                    url: "{% url 'bms:content_checklist_name_url' %}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    //async: false,
                    //dataType : 'json',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        //msg = json.loads(request.POST.get('msg', ''))
                        //alert('{{ msg }}');
                        var a = "{{msg}}";
                        //console.log(msg);
                        if (a === "Duplicate Entry. This Course Code already exists.")
                        {
                            Swal.fire(
                            '',
                            'Duplicate Entry. This Course Code already exists.',
                            'error'
                            )
                            e.preventDefault();

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Swal.fire(
                            '',
                            'Entries have been saved.',
                            'success'
                            )
                            e.preventDefault();

                        }
                    },
                    failure: function(data)
                    {
                        //alert('Got an error dude');
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                window.stop();
            }
         }
       )
 }
```

I have tried to set the timer to even 15s, not working at all, seems like some  refresh timer built in sweet alert flushed the pop up box:

```
                            Swal.fire({
                        title: '',
                        text: 'Entries have been saved.',
                        type: 'success',
                        timer: 15000
                        })
```

Comment: what `preventDefault()` has to do with all this?

Comment: I want to stop the pop up's quick disappearing, let the user click "OK" first

Comment: You know what submitting a form does? Why do you think the `$.ajax()` call after it would be executed? And what's with that `window.stop()` call?

Comment: @Andreas submitting data using post to a url for processing.   I have checked in console, the ajax does runs.  window.stop()----> when user click other places instead of confirm, it would not proceed